# How to config webpack for media assets & font for reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I used a awesome boilerplate for `react` application, I wanna to use `media` like pictures or videos and fonts in my application. the reference link is [here](https://github.com/amerllica/react-server-render-example).

- How to config all required resources with `react`. I am getting error after add assets configuration in `webpack.config.js`.
- If anyone have idea about how config it tell me. I wrote like below:

I use this config:

```
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
     use: [
             {
               loader: 'file-loader'
             }
     ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the main link of example is [this link](https://github.com/DigitalKwarts/react-server-render-example) and the stable version of it will be always here.

For your exact answer you can use below code to import the `file-loader` for all media:

```
    {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            limit: 1024,
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            publicPath: 'font/',
            outputPath: 'font/'
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            limit: 1024,
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            publicPath: 'img/',
            outputPath: 'img/'
        }
    }
```

After this setting you can access to your media by using this these addresses:

**`CSS` :**
background: url('./img/myMedia.jpg');

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'as-you-wish';
    src: url('./font/yourFont.eot');
}
```

**`DOM` :**

```
<img src='/dist/img/myMedia.jpg' />
```

But remember this config is in `rule:` after the second object, so your result config must be like these:

```
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|jss)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules[\/\\])(?!mqtt)/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'shebang-loader',
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.pcss$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules\/)/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: true,
                                importLoaders: 1,
                                localIdentName: '[local]',
                                sourceMap: true,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                config: {
                                    path: `${__dirname}/../postcss/postcss.config.js`,
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 1024,
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    publicPath: 'font/',
                    outputPath: 'font/'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 1024,
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    publicPath: 'img/',
                    outputPath: 'img/'
                }
            }
        ],
    }
```

So after it pay attention to `[name].[ext]` in `name:`, I change it to `[hash:base64:5].[ext]` for production version.

For any issues, leave an issue message in [Github repo](https://gitlab.com/amerllica/react-server-render-example).